# Going back to mapview after having opened a newcontroller from an annotation disclosure button

Tags: viewcontroller, ibaction

I am making an application where there are multiple pins in a map. (using xcode for iOS apps) When I click on the pins, the callout comes up with a disclosure button that when pressed brings up a new viewcontroller (which I use as the detail view.. is this correct?)

I am currently having problems going back to the original viewcontroller after viewing the new viewcontroller.

How should I proceed to go back to the map view?

I have tried with the -(IBAction)Back; command and linking it to a button on the new viewcontroller, however when I click it in the simulator, a black screen comes up and no error is shown in the output..

Any help would be appreciated!

I used the following to view the new view controller:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control {


    if ([view.annotation.title isEqualToString:@"..."]) {

            ...Controller *sampleView = [[...Controller alloc] init];
            [self presentModalViewController:sampleView animated:YES];

    }

    if ([view.annotation.title isEqualToString:@"..."]){
       ...ViewController *sampleView = [[...ViewController alloc] init];
        [self presentModalViewController:sampleView animated:YES];
    }
}
```

EDIT 1:
This is the error code I get after making the change..

```
2013-06-30 18:02:30.386 lam[15156:13d03] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] loaded the "...Controller" nib but the view outlet was not set.'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1e2d012 0x126ae7e 0x1e2cdeb 0xf88c8 0xf8dc8 0xf8ff8 0xf9232 0x104c25 0x3043a3 0x101ee3 0x102167 0xfee0071 0x374c 0x10deb1a 0x10ea28e 0x82f617f 0x127e705 0x1b2c0 0x1b258 0xdc021 0xdc57f 0xdb6e8 0x4acef 0x4af02 0x28d4a 0x1a698 0x1d88df9 0x1db0f3f 0x1db096f 0x1dd3734 0x1dd2f44 0x1dd2e1b 0x1d877e3 0x1d87668 0x17ffc 0x2842 0x2775)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How did your `calloutAccessoryControlTapped` "bring up" this new view controller?

If you used a modal transition (e.g. such as `presentViewController` or modal segue), then you would dismiss it with `dismissViewControllerAnimated`. If you used the deprecated `presentModalViewController`, then you'd use the `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated`, but then again, you probably shouldn't use the deprecated methods unless you need to support iOS versions prior to 5.0. Use the `presentViewController` and `dismissViewControllerAnimated` renditions, instead. Anyway, you might end up with an `IBAction` method like:

```
- (IBAction)handleDoneButton:(id)sender
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

If you used push transition (e.g. `pushViewController` or push segue), then you'd generally just avail yourself of the built-in "back" button, but if you need your own button to pop this controller, you'd use an `IBAction` with `popViewControllerAnimated`. For example:

```
- (IBAction)handleDoneButton:(id)sender
{
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Or, if your `calloutAccessoryControlTapped` used a `performSegueWithIdentifier`, then you could either use the above technique or, in iOS 6 and above, you could define the following unwind segue in the view controller that has the map:

```
- (IBAction)backToMap:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue
{
    // do whatever you want
}
```

And then you can <kbd>control</kbd>-drag from the button to the exit outlet in the bar under the scene, and you should see this `backToMap` unwind segue.

---

Regarding your error, it means that your NIB's root view is not set. Select the view and look at its outlets. You should see something like:

[image: if view set up proper]

If not, (a) make sure you set your "File's owner" to be your view controller class; and (b) right click on "File's owner"; (c) drag from the "o" next to the "view" in the popover view to the actual view:

[image]

Also, when creating the view controller, you'd probably want to specify which NIB to use:

```
ViewController *controller;
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
    controller = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];
} else {
    controller = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController_iPad" bundle:nil];
}
```

Comment: I just updated my question with the code i used to bring up the new viewcontroller

Comment: Thank you very much. Where exactly do I have to put dismisspresentViewControllerAnimated?

Comment: @DCB Create a `IBAction` method for your "dismiss" button in your second view controller, and then put the `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated` code there.

Comment: So in my .h file, i but -(IBAction)dismiss; 
and then in my .m file, what is the exact code I'm supposed to use? 
-(IBAction)dismiss {
dismissViewControllerAnimated ..?
}

Comment: Thank you so much! As soon as I have a moment, I will try and accept your answer! :)

Comment: I have changed "presentModalViewController" to "presentViewController", but now I get a warning: "Instance method '-presentViewController:animated:' not found (return type defaults to "id") and when I run it in the simulator, it gives me a lldb error when I click the button linked to this action...

Comment: I have added the completion:nil, but I still get an error. I have added the error as an edit in the question.

Comment: I believe that everything is already correct.. the controller isn't exactly the same as the nib. i have two nib files for the firstViewController, 1. FirstViewController_iPhone.xib and 2- FirstViewController_iPad.xib

Is there anyway you could help me solve this without the chat?

Comment: I did everything you posted, but I still get the error... i know this is probably a really easy thing to resolve...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32646/discussion-between-dcb-and-rob)

Comment: Hello @Rob, i have a question again similar to this question (i have already created another question..)

Instead of having the second view controller in nibs, can i use storyboards? In other words, i would like to link the second tab to a storyboard instead of the xib that i am currently using. I know that the purpose of storyboards are to have connections between them and using both may seem a bit strange.. but as of now i don't have the time to rewrite the other 2 tabs. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20458989/using-nibs-and-storyboards-together/20495603

Comment: I'm not exactly sure where i'm supposed to put instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:

If i where to send you the file like last time, could you give it a look?

Comment: OK... 

But then where does storyboardWithName: go?

Comment: @DCB BTW, I've added an answer to your other question. I'd suggest you delete any of your comments here that are unrelated to the question listed above. In the future, post any follow-up comments to the appropriate question.