# Using nibs and storyboards together

Tags: ios, storyboard, uitabbarcontroller, xib, nib

From what I have read on the internet, nibs and storyboards are comparable with each other in the same project. Now I am creating a tabbed application and would like to do the following:

Tab 1: constructed with nibs,

Tab 2: constructed with storyboards,

Tab 3: constructed with nibs

Initially I created everything with nibs so in my delegate I was passing from one tab to the next with this code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    UIViewController *viewController1, *viewController2, *viewController3;
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        viewController1 = [[[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil] autorelease];
        viewController2 = [[[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil] autorelease];
        viewController3 = [[[ThirdViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ThirdViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    } else {
        viewController1 = [[[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController_iPad" bundle:nil] autorelease];
        viewController2 = [[[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController_iPad" bundle:nil] autorelease];
        viewController3 = [[[ThirdViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ThirdViewController_iPad" bundle:nil] autorelease];

    }
    self.tabBarController = [[[UITabBarController alloc] init] autorelease];
    self.tabBarController.viewControllers = @[viewController1, viewController2, viewController3];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;



}
```

Instead of having the SecondViewController_*.xib I need to have the SecondViewController_*.storyboard. How do I do this? Can I just change the name "SecondViewController_*.nib" to "SecondViewController_*.storyboard"? I don't think this would work..

Any help would be very appreciated!!

EDIT: 
the code i was using :

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        self.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Events", @"Events");
        self.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"second"];
    }
    return self; }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do what you're suggesting by creating a storyboard and then creating a `SecondViewController` scene inside it.  In code, you would then replace `initWithNibName:` with calls to `storyboardWithName:` and `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:`.

However, since a major feature in storyboards is the ability to tie multiple controllers together and define relationships between them, it's hard to imagine why doing it for one controller would be a good idea.

Comment: Thank you for your comment Phillip!
I'm afraid that I didn't understand what I need to do.. 
First of all, what do you mean with "create a SecondViewController scene inside"? 
What do I have to replace with "instantiateViewControllerWithIndentifier:" with?

Comment: 1) When you put a view controller into a storyboard, it creates a "scene" that matches the type or the controller's subclass.  Therefore "a SecondViewController scene" is one of those where you've made the view controller a `SecondViewController`.  2) You currently call `initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController_iPhone"`...I'm saying you would need to remove it and call those other two methods instead.

Comment: ok, part 1 is clear. now the only issue is part 2. where do i put storyboardWithName: and where do i put instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: ?

Answer (score 1):

As Phillip said, just use `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier`.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    UIViewController *viewController1, *viewController2, *viewController3;
    UIStoryboard *storyboard;
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        viewController1 = [[[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil] autorelease];
        storyboard      = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"iPhone" bundle:nil];
        viewController2 = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Second"];
        viewController3 = [[[ThirdViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ThirdViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    } else {
        viewController1 = [[[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController_iPad" bundle:nil] autorelease];
        storyboard      = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"iPad" bundle:nil];
        viewController2 = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Second"];
        viewController3 = [[[ThirdViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ThirdViewController_iPad" bundle:nil] autorelease];

    }
    self.tabBarController = [[[UITabBarController alloc] init] autorelease];
    self.tabBarController.viewControllers = @[viewController1, viewController2, viewController3];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

This assumes that your storyboards were called `iPhone.storyboard` and `iPad.storyboard`, but change the above code to match whatever you call these two storyboards. Furthermore, this again assumes that you defined that scene to bear a "Storyboard ID" of `Second` (you do that by selecting the view controller in IB and going to the "Identity Inspector") and also that you specified your "custom class" there, too:

[image]

---

For `SecondViewController`, you should replace you `initWithNibName:bundle:` method with:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];

    if (self) {
        self.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Events", @"Events");
        self.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"second"];
    }

    return self; 
}
```

Comment: @DCB If you forgive the editorial, I must say, while the above technique shows you how to combine storyboards and NIBs, I'd suggest you just go ahead and make the transition to storyboards. You have probably wasted more time trying to figure out how to make the two coexist than you would have spent if you just shifted everything to storyboards at the beginning.

Comment: Great! thanks! now i have one issue that has arisen with this.. on the tab bar on the bottom, i don't have the icon or name of the tab anymore.. before hand i was calling it with a certain code. this won't work because it was using nibs. how do i fix this? (i have updated the question with the code i was using)

Comment: @DCB For the storyboard-based view controller (the second one), use `initWithCoder` rather than `initWithNibName`.

Comment: But in my .h i now have 
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

Comment: @DCB Your question said you used `initWithNibName`. That's what I'm suggesting you replace with `initWithCoder`. The `initWithStyle` is the initialization method for a `UITableViewCell` subclass. But we're talking about your view controller.

Comment: so its supposed to be:

Comment: - (id)initWithCoder:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        self.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Events", @"Events");
        self.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"second"];
    }
    return self;
}

Comment: @DCB No, please refer to the `UIViewController` Class Reference documentation for the appropriate signature for `initWithCoder`. See my updated answer with example.

Comment: i'm putting this in the secondviewcontroller.m but it won't show anything, no title, no image..

Comment: @DCB Have you confirmed that the scene's view controller base class has been set to `SecondViewController` (see identity inspector screen snapshot above)? Perhaps put breakpoints in `initWithCoder` (which will get called when you add the controller to the tab bar controller) and `viewDidLoad` (which will get called when you tab on that second tab) and confirm that the view controller is getting instantiated correctly. But I confirmed that this technique works fine, so you must have overlooked something simple in your project.

Comment: everything was right, all i did was delete and re-insert the view controller in the storyboard.. strange! but it works now, thank you!!